# TYPO3 8.7 backend - Change range for datepicker

Tags: datepicker, backend, typo3-8.x

I need to enter the birth year before 1900 in the TYPO3 backend.

If I try to write year 1879 as a birthday, TYPO3 changes the date to 2018.

Is it possible to change it and how?

This is my TCA:

```
"year_of_birth" => [
    "exclude" => 0,
    'label' => 'LLL:EXT:xxx/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xml:fe_users.year_of_birth',
    'config' => [
        'type' => 'input',
        'renderType' => 'inputDateTime',
        'dbType' => 'date',
        'eval' => 'date',
        'range' => [
            'upper' => mktime(0, 0, 0, 12, 31, 1960), //'31-12-1960',            
            'lower' => mktime(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1860) //'01-01-1860',
        ],        
    ],
],
```

[image] [image]

Answer (score 0):

up until now the date/time fields in TYPO3 are represented by an integer and based on unixtime which gives you a range (if you include negative values) from 1903 until 2039.
Also the Javascript which realises the wizards. as there are some specials in the evaluation (+1 equals to 'tommorow', 01012000+40 gives the 41 day in the year 2000 (Feb 10th)), the resulting date is 'guessed'[1] and you get completely differnt results.

You need to write your own wizards, which are not based on unixtime.

[1] it is not really guessed, there are some patterns which are tried and a matching result is shown